# Event 'moveend' doesn't occur if swipe is interrupted by click

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Here is a [page](http://jsfiddle.net/6bZv6/2/) with a map. All map events are captured and displayed in the console :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
          layers: [layer], zoom: 13,
          center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(324002, 6312782)
        });

        events = ['preaddlayer', 'addlayer', 'preremovelayer', 'removelayer', 'changelayer', 'movestart', 'move', 'moveend', 'zoomstart', 'zoomend', 'changebaselayer', 'updatesize'];
        for (e in events) map.events.register(events[e], this, function(evt) { console.log(evt.type); });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I swipe (t.i. push left mouse button, drag and release button while dragging) the map with mouse, then we see in the console `movestart`, several `move` and, finally, when map stops moving, `moveend`, as expected.

However, if I click while view is moving, then `moveend` doesn't occur.

Why is that? How to fix it?

Result is the same on Chrome 31, Firefox 26 and Opera 18.

Comment: OpenLayers bug, most likely? Looks like clicking on the map interrupts moving in a way that "swallows" `moveend`.